# Fetch broken rss feed with missmatched xml tag

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, rss, str-replace, mismatch

I am trying to fetch rss feed from a site with broken rss feed due to xml parsing error, mismatched tag. 
Is there a way like `str_replace` (Which I've tried without success) mismatched tags? And why is not `str_replace();` working?

Comment: What technologies are you working with?

Comment: I am trying to create a wordpress function, so basically with php @NicGibson

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what the data looks like.